# Unable use write() to write to standard out

Tags: c, unix, posix

I'm trying to use write() to write a char to standard out one byte at a time. The program compiles and runs fine but the output isn't turning out quite right. Now I'm trying to get it to run with write but I'm not getting any output in the console.

```
void myfunction(char *s, int fd, int n){

    for(int i = 0; i != sizeof(s) - 1; ++i){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", &s[i]);  // This correctly prints out the string

        if( write(fd, &s, 1) < 0){ // This will not print to the console
             perror("Error: Write problems.");  // Have not gotten any errors yet   
        }

        wastesometime(n);  // This just calls a for loop that runs n times
    }
}


sizeN = sprintf(buffer, "This is process %d with ID %ld and parent id %ld\n", i, (long)getpid(), (long)getppid());

myfunction(buffer, STDOUT_FILENO, n);
```

Currently I'm getting output in the form of this from fprintf:

```
process 2 with ID 27711 and parent id 27710
rocess 2 with ID 27711 and parent id 27710
ocess 2 with ID 27711 and parent id 27710
cess 2 with ID 27711 and parent id 27710
ess 2 with ID 27711 and parent id 27710
ss 2 with ID 27711 and parent id 27710
s 2 with ID 27711 and parent id 27710
 2 with ID 27711 and parent id 27710
2 with ID 27711 and parent id 27710
 with ID 27711 and parent id 27710
with ID 27711 and parent id 27710
ith ID 27711 and parent id 27710
th ID 27711 and parent id 27710
h ID 27711 and parent id 27710
 ID 27711 and parent id 27710
ID 27711 and parent id 27710
D 27711 and parent id 27710
 27711 and parent id 27710
27711 and parent id 27710
7711 and parent id 27710
711 and parent id 27710
11 and parent id 27710
1 and parent id 27710
 and parent id 27710
and parent id 27710
nd parent id 27710
d parent id 27710
 parent id 27710
parent id 27710
arent id 27710
rent id 27710
ent id 27710
nt id 27710
t id 27710
 id 27710
id 27710
d 27710
 27710
27710
7710
710
10
0
```

But I am trying to get this output using write instead of fprintf, for every process:

```
This is process 2 with ID 27711 and parent id 27710
```

This may be relevant but `fprintf(stderr, %d\n", &s[i])` works and `fprintf(stdout, %d\n", &s[i])`? I believe `stderr` gets priority but I didn't think that the other output wouldn't get printed at all?

Yes, I have done some research but most answers I've found use `fwrite()` or are in C++ and are therefore not what I'm looking for.

Comment: how is `s` defined?  What is the output that isn't right and what do you expect?

Comment: Are you *sure* nothing is sent to `stdout`?  Not even, say, non-printing characters?

Comment: What is `STDOUT_FILENO` defined as?

Comment: You wrote `fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", i)` and said in your comment that it "correctly prints out the string", but `%d` does not print out a string!  Nor is it printing out the characters of the string -- it's just printing "0 1 2..." up to the number of characters in the string.  WHat does the array `s` actually contain?

Comment: Looks like `s` is a string (char array) and `&s` should be `&s[i]`.

Comment: I second R's suggestion.  Try `write(STDOUT_FILENO, s+i, 1)`.  And if that works, skip the loop and try `write(STDOUT_FILENO, s, strlen(s))`.

Comment: I updated my question so hopefully it is more clear what i'm asking.

Comment: And `sizeof(s)` should be `strlen(s)`?

Comment: I have used both `sizeof` and `strlen` and didn't notice a difference. Either way the `fprintf` works but `write` does not.

Comment: @K-Log this is a bit of a waste of time if you don't show your full code. `sizeof` and `strlen` are fundamentally different, I suggest you research the difference before picking one at random.

Comment: @SteveSummit I tried both of your suggestions but neither produced any output to the console.

Comment: @Retr0id I would but my full code is very long and has very little to due with what I'm asking aside from existing in the same program.

Comment: Problems statements should  [include MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some details missing, but based on what you've posted so far, this ought to work:

```
void myfunction(char *s, int fd, int n) {

    if( write(fd, s, strlen(s)) < 0) {
         perror("Error: Write problems.");
    }

    wastesometime(n);
}
```

Let's make sure we understand what's going on here.  Within `myfunction`, the argument `s` is a pointer to `char`, and more specifically, it points to the first character of a null-terminated array of characters, which is C's definition of a string.

The `write` function you're trying to use also accepts a pointer to `char`.  However, it does not insist (or expect) that the pointer be specifically to a null-terminated string; it can be a pointer to any array of characters.  Since `write` does not assume a null-terminated string, you must tell it precisely how many characters you want it to write.

Since you're starting with a null-terminated string, you can compute the actual number of characters in the string (which is precisely the number you need to pass as the third argument to `write`) by calling the standard `strlen` function, as I've shown.

Your problem may have something to do with `STDOUT_FILENO` not being defined correctly.  Please try all four of these calls:

```
myfunction(buffer, 1, n);

myfunction(buffer, 2, n);

myfunction(buffer, fileno(stdout), n);

printf("STDOUT_FILENO = %d\n", STDOUT_FILENO);
```

Comment: I doubt this is the problem. `STDOUT_FILENO` is defined in unistd.h and will be correct unless you un- and re-defined it.

Comment: @R.. I doubt it, too, but the OP claims that `write(STDOUT_FILENO, s, strlen(s))` didn't work, so I'm exploring options...

Comment: I have tried use 1 & 2 instead of STDOUT/STDIN and neither produced any output. I also tried your other suggestions and am still getting no output. I don’t know if this was clear in my question but only stderr with fprintf seems to work for printing to the console.

Answer (score 1):

```
void myfunction(char *s, int fd, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if (write(fd, s + i, 1) < 0)
        {
             perror("Error: Write problems.");
        }
        sleep(n);
    }
}
```

You don't need to send &s to write, because s is already a pointer, already contains an adress... and sending &s is like sending the adress of an adress... Also, dont forget to increment that adress s in your loop or you will write the same character over and over.

When you use printf (or any of its variants), you can use %c to print a character, you use %s to print a string (char *)

Comment: I already tried 1 instead of STDOUT_FILENO and it still produced no output along. s + i had no effect either.

Comment: sizeof(s) will return the size of a pointer, you should use "i < strlen(s)" to get the size of your string. But the main problem in your loop is definitely &s

Comment: @Eskombro: Only if `s` is a pointer. Presumably it's an array.

Comment: In the function parameter s is a char*, so a pointer, isn't it?